# ASP.NET MVC, EF, 'IsReference' property specified was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework, I suddenly get this strange error after publishing my asp.net mvc project onto my Win2003 server:

> [CustomAttributeFormatException: 'IsReference' property specified was not found.]

The error occurs when I need to update or delete an entity.

I haven't changed anything (and yes, it's actually true :-) in my model, I only recompiled it when publishing. It worked yesterday and the server haven't changed either.

Any idea on what has gone wrong here?

Thanks in advance. Help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on the server. Update it.